# Solr query and double quotes

Tags: solr

When I am passing queries in solr I pass them as strings (“blah blah”). I am doing this because I have encoding problems with Greek (my input field accept Greek characters only as string). But solr sees the characters inside the quotes as an “exact match” term. Is there a way to remove the double quotes from Solr?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes before passing the query to Solr?

Comment: It seems like you should fix your encoding problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use solr.StrField in your schema, it makes sense that you get exact matches, see:
http://azeckoski.blogspot.com/2009/06/tricky-solr-schema-issue-with-strfield.html

You should use solr.TextField really, that would allow you to use Greek analyzers. I don't quite understand why it accepts Greek characters only as strings. Can you explain ?

About Greek lower case and stemming:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Greek
On the other hand, please note that if you use stemming, you won't be able to do exact matches anymore...